# Google Sheets: Reading a cell on multiple tabs and sending email if >= date

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am a very new to this and got most of this off of examples online.
I need help.
I am trying to read a specific cell (E10) and if the current date is equal to or past that cell date I want to send myself an email with the notification.
I am doing this to alert when our truck fleet is in need of oil changes.

I have specific tabs for each truck I want this to read and get cell values for.

I got it to work for a single sheet but when I tried to do multiple, things got messy.
Don't judge me.

```
  function emailAlert() {
  // today's date information
  var today = new Date();
  var todayMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
  var todayDay = today.getDate();
  var todayYear = today.getFullYear();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var selectedSheets = ["Truck #1","Truck #2","Truck #3","Truck #4","Truck#5","Truck #6","Truck #7","Truck #8","Truck #10","Truck #12","White Van"]
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();

   var expireDateFormat = Utilities.formatDate(
      new Date(value),
      'ET',
      'MM/dd/yyyy'
    );

  sheets.forEach(selectedSheets)

      
    var value = sheets.getSheetValues(10,5,1,1);
    Logger.log(value);

//expiration date information
    var expireDateMonth = new Date(value).getMonth() + 1;
    var expireDateDay = new Date(value).getDate();
    var expireDateYear = new Date(value).getFullYear();

      

    

    
      


    // email information
    var row1 = 3;
    var col1 = 6;

    var truckName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row1, col1).getValue();

    var subject = '';
    var message =
      ' A Truck Needs Your Help:. ' + 'Check Oil Change Date'
      '\n' +
      ' Truck: ' +
      truckName;

        
        
    //checking for today

    if(selectedSheets)
      expireDateMonth <= todayMonth &&
      expireDateDay <= todayDay &&
      expireDateYear <= todayYear
        
    {
      var subject =
        'A Truck Needs Your Help: ' + value;
      MailApp.sendEmail('example@gmail.com', subject, message);
      Logger.log('Sent');
    }
  
}
```

This is what I currently have.

It seems to all go wrong at:  sheets.forEach(selectedSheets)